# Getting Values From a Variable Returned From PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following variable returned from php to JavaScript: `[{"id":"34"}, {"id":"35"}, ...]`. I would like, the value of "id". How do I do that using JSON?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your current code that returns the "variable" to JS. Are you asking how to write some sort of loop that does something with the id from each item in the array, or...?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var obj = [{"id":"34"}, {"id":"35"}];
console.log(obj[0]['id']);
```

**Note:** To make it dynamic use JS `loop`

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76qabk1a/20/)